# onClick inside of a <img

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jestjs

Not able to perform a test for a click event that is inside of an image tag.

Here is the code that I am trying to test it. Not able to test both click events due to setState

```
<td className="centertext">
   <input type='radio' name='req' onClick={() => {this.handleRequestClick(titles[i][j].RequestId, titles[i][j].Name, titles[i][j].Content)}} />
 </td>
 <td className="modal-add-window-td">{i}</td>
 <td className="modal-add-window-td">
   <div>{titles[i][j].Name}</div>
 </td>
 <td className="modal-add-window-td">
   <img className='request-info'src={infoSVG} alt='Info' onClick={() => {this.showDescription(titles[i][j].Name, titles[i][j].Description)}} />
 </td>
```

Here is what I have tried to so far but getting the following msg:
   Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Using Jest and enzyme - memory router and mount the components

```
     it("Test click event on show Description", () => {
     wrapper.find('AddViewModal').setState({
        titles:[[{
         Requests:{
           Name:""
           }}
       ]]

       }),
      wrapper.update();  

  expect(wrapper.find('AddViewModal').find('img').props().src).toEqual('../../Images/chartImages/info.svg')
     //wrapper.find('AddViewModal').find('img[alt="Info"]').simulate('click')

     });
```

Comment: did you try this `wrapper.find('AddViewModal').find('img').simulate('click')` ?

Comment: I did - node cant be found

Comment: what is `AddViewModal` ? is the rest of the code valid ? is it working?

Comment: class name. Yes the rest of the code is valid and click events are tested

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii any ideas ?

Comment: could you create a repo so I could replicate?

Comment: `Could not find module in path: '../../components/SideLabels/sideLabels' relative to '/src/containers/Schedule/Schedule.js'`

Comment: dont worry about that - thats something different.

Answer (score 1):

did you try findWhere?

```
element.findWhere(node => node.hasClass("request-info"))
```

If it doesn't, can you verify if findWhere traverses the node you're targeting?

Comment: the set state was incorrect, Once i figure out - test passed and coverage was affected

Comment: thanks for the help but a small mistake on setstate can take you hours of testing sometimes

Comment: one of your previous comments yes , wrapper.find('AddViewModal').find('img').simulate('click') . I did not know you could   find('img') like that .

Comment: @user9191 consider marking it as correct answer then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you get the right state otherwise node wont be found

```
   it("Test click event on show Description", () => {
   baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
   wrapper.find('Component').setState({
     Requests: [{
      Name: 'testing'
    }]  
  })
 wrapper.update();
 wrapper.find('Componentl').find('img').simulate('click')
```